# Separate languages for dialog and captions on Xbox 360 (Just Cause 2)?

Tags: xbox-360, just-cause-2

I am studying German at the moment, and my language on my Xbox 360 is set to it, to pick up a bit while playing games. This works well with non-dialog-heavy games, because it's easy enough to figure out what something means.

However, I'm playing the campaign of Just Cause 2, and someone will often give you instructions on what to do, and it's pretty important to understand what they say. I'd like to have closed captions on in English, with everything else (including dialog) still in German. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

While it is possible to show captions, there is no way to set separate languages.

You can play the game in English, or in German, but not both.